# C# Word 2007 Add In Regex

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I'm creating a visual studio C# word add in application. Inside the Ribbon.cs, below is the regex code inside the button event to find and replace.

My concern is, for the ** marks, I need to find entire word document and replace the finding text with regex. Kindly advise. Thank you.

Regex.Replace(**, @"Find", "Replace");

Comment: VBA example - [Finding and Replacing Text or Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx) - note that `ActiveDocument.Content` returns a Range for the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Regex with Word, since the word document is no string.
But you can use Word's builtin search and replace using wildcards.

Here is how it looks like in VBA, notice the `MatchWildcards`property.
You will be able to rewrite it in C# easily.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Find"
    .Replacement.Text = "Replace"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, May I know using wildcards can I replace the text like regex, for example find A([s-u]*)S, in replace, B$1B. I mean the dollar factor.

Comment: No, the Word wildcard syntax is completely different from the regex syntax, but it also pretty powerful.
There is lots of documentation about this syntax on the web, for example here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1